# Google calendar feed not showing events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a public google calendar. The feed tests okay, but I can't get the events to show up in fullcalendar. My feed IS the XML feed for sharing. I've read similar posts but they didn't help.

http://drcraigjohnson.net/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/theme.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,                        
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jl2um2s9odbrtj7lt3bn9817vg%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {
                window.open(event.url);
                return false;
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to test this with jsfiddle - I guess I don't have access to your Google Calendar. Anyway, a couple of things you might correct here:

1. Remove the **HTML** comment from the JavaScript section! The one which starts with `<!--` in the script tag
2. You have an extra comma after the `eventClick` callback - remove that. That should have thrown a syntax error for you though. Your JS wont run with syntax errors.

Try checking your API calls with browser tools (Chrome Dev tools or Firebug) to debug further.

Comment: HTML comment and extra comma removed.Google calendar IS public. No luck. Here's my XML feed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jl2um2s9odbrtj7lt3bn9817vg%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

jsfiddle is over my head.

Comment: Still need help. Suggestions?

Comment: The google calendar gives me a 403 Forbidden error. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/9A83S/

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Make sure google calendar "Share only my free/busy information" is **unchecked**. Tested by using a known working feed, i.e. google holiday xml which worked. Then i knew it something re: my feed. Thanks again. Problem solved!!!